# SELECT AVG displaying just one result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-database

For a garage database, attempting to find the average score for manufacturer components during section testing. This following SQL seems to work perfectly:

```
SELECT component.manufacturer_id, AVG(section.grades) AS Grade_Average 
FROM section
INNER JOIN component
  ON section.mod_id=component.cid
GROUP BY component.manufacturer_id
```

But will only give one row of results (i.e. for only one manufacturer_id)

Comment: Are their any more `manufacturer_id` in the table?

Comment: "will only give one row of results" or "does only give one row of results".  Because the GROUP BY will return one average for every unique manufacturer ID it finds in the JOIN.  If you only get one result, it means there's only one manufacturer ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all `manufacturer_id` values, then you you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT component.manufacturer_id, 
  AVG(section.grades) AS Grade_Average 
FROM component
LEFT JOIN section
  ON status.mod_id=component.cid  
GROUP BY component.manufacturer_id;
```

Your current query is using an `INNER JOIN` which will only return the rows that match between both tables.

You also are using `status.mod_id` in the `JOIN` but you are joining on `section`, do you need to add a join to `status` or what that typed wrong in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

you have an inner join between section and component.  If there are no matching records in both tables for a particular manufacturer, that will filter them out completely.